# Trouble with g++ & libpqxx lib

Tags: g++, libpqxx

I've very simple example, and can't correctly build it, I was using next arguments:

> g++ -lpq -libpqxx -Wall -o "pg" "pg.cpp"  (in dir: /home/user)
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

or

> returned 1 exit status g++ -libpqxx -Wall -o "pg" "pg.cpp" 
>   (in dir: /home/user)
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.5/../../../../i586-suse-linux/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -libpqxx collect2: ld

but everywere had error.
libpqxx succ installed

> @lisuse-home:~> locate libpqxx | grep /lib/
>   /usr/lib/libpqxx-3.1.so
>   /usr/lib/libpqxx.la
>   /usr/lib/libpqxx.so
>   /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libpqxx.pc

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgconfig.html . It can help you find include/paths/library names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compiling g++ `-libpqxx-3.1 -Wall -c "%f"`

building `g++  -Wall -o "%e" /usr/lib/libpqxx-3.1.so  "%f"`

Answer (score 3):

```
g++ filename.cpp -o target -lpqxx
```

`-lpqxx` should take care of `-lpq`. If for some reason it does not find `pq`, find `pq` and put it in the same directory as `pqxx`.